# Редактировать текст таким образом, что бы все названия глав были большими буквами

Tags: c#, файлы, текст, редактор-текста

Задача заключается в следующем: Необходимо изменить в файле написание всех названий глав на большие буквы. Название главы выделено пропуском одной строки перед и после самого текста.
Как реализовать это в C#?
Не прошу полного решения, интересует сама суть выполнения данного задания

Comment: Тоесть Вы сообществу SO задачу ставите? сильно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть решения:

- Прочитать все строки из файла в массив.
- Пройти циклом от второй строки до предпоследней.
- В цикле проверять строку до и после текущей. Если оказались пустыми - менять регистр букв текущей строки.
- Записать массив строк обратно в выходной файл.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < count-1; i++)
            {
                if ((a[i] == " ") && (a[i + 2] == " "))
                    counter2++;
            }`
Что не так? Почему не работает?

Comment: @Дмитрий скорее всего проверки стоит делать на =="". Или через String.IsNullOrWhitespace(a[i]). проверять надо i-1 и i+1. внутри if написать a[i] = a[i].ToUpper(). И пройтись по шагам в отдладке, просматривая что происходит - кнопка F10 в студии. но вообще - движетесь в правильном направлении :)

Comment: @Дмитрий если совсем упретесь в тупик - создайте новый вопрос, приведите там весь ваш код, и напишите что именно не работает.

Comment: Большое спасибо!
Там новая проблема, описал тут: http://goo.gl/QoUm4k